# Stackexchange.com is broken (some of the time)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

I currently get the following error message when accessing anything on [http://stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/):

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.
> Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
> error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

This appeared a bit earlier, then it worked for a while, and now I get the error again.

Comment: Reproduced, and some flairs are also borken.

Comment: Reproduced by a number of other people as well as myself

Comment: Now works for me.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We went through a round of server upgrades last week.  All of the issues we had should be fixed now.